# SQL Server 2017 MLS - cant add python package

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, installation, python

I'm new-ish to MLS and have been trying to add new python packages like  attrs  to the python but it hasn't been working.

Our set up is SQL Server 2017 with CU14 on Win 2016.

Python version is 3.5.2

The usual command I run is:

```
pip install attrs
```

and I run this from the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\Scripts`
but nothing happens.....

it says "collecting attrs" then nothing.

When I look in the So I updated a dev VM to SQL Server 2017 CU22, and it installed Python 3.7 and tried same thing - it worked.

But this doesn't help me as we already have existing SQL Server 2017 servers with this package in it and the dude who originally set this up is gone, so any help appreciated.

All the installs are default, nothing special.

Comment: TO help yourself or to provide enough information for us to be able to help you take a look at the setup log files

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=SQL%20Server%20Setup%20creates%20log,folder%20name%20format%20is%20YYYYMMDD_hhmmss.

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out, it seems the VM it was running in was too high VMware hardware level.
When I dropped the hardware back to a lower version, it worked.

Thanks